# Client/Server Program in Java - Streams

Tags: java, networking, stream, client, server

I have a problem getting the output that i want from the code that i have implemented in order to create the server/client program...it's just a really simple one, and i don't know why i don't get what i want.

Here is the code of the server:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1025);
        System.out.println("Porting...");
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String s = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server read: " + s);
        out.write("Got it");

        socket.close();
        System.out.println("Server Exit");
```

The client:

```
    System.out.print("Connecting...");
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",1025);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        out.write("Hello, Server");

        String s = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client Recieved: " + s);

        socket.close();
        System.out.println("Client Exit");
```

I try to get the Hello, Server output, instead i just get the "connecting" syso from the client (which i just did to see if it works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you wrote on the stream you have to flush the stream by calling flush() method on the outputstream. Else the stream will be flushed once the stream buffer is full.

```
 out.flush();
```

Also you have to make sure that enter the new line character to mention the end of line. Because readLine() waits for string with newline().

```
A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r')



  out.write("Hello, Server\n");
            out.flush();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Shriram!